# Random Alphanumeirc increment

Tags: java

Hey Guys i made a program that will increment any
EX: abc123sx asd123213adsasd2.

But im having a problem with these kind of numbers.
EX: 001, 1abc, abc1

```
String str1 = "EnterIDHere";
    String temp2 = new String();
    String Temp = new String();
    char[] charID = new char[str1.length()];
    charID = str1.toCharArray();
    str1.trim();        
    for(int intCtr1 = 0; intCtr1<str1.length();intCtr1++){
        if(Character.isDigit(charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-1])){
            Temp += charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-1];    
            if(Character.isLetter(charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-2])){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int intCtr1 = 0; intCtr1<str1.length();intCtr1++){
        if(Character.isLetter(charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-1])){
            temp2 += charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-1];
            if(Character.isDigit(charID[str1.length()-intCtr1-2])){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("NumPart "+new StringBuilder(Temp).reverse().toString());
    System.out.println("LastPart "+new StringBuilder(temp2).reverse().toString());
    System.out.println("FrontPart "+str1.substring(0,(str1.length()-(temp2.length()+Temp.length()))));
    int Num = Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(Temp).reverse().toString());
    Num += 1;
            String Front = str1.substring(0,(str1.length()-(temp2.length()+Temp.length())));
    //System.out.println(str1.substring(0,(str1.length()-(temp2.length()+Temp.length())))+""+Num+""+temp2);
            strReturn = String.format("%s%d%s",Front,Num,temp2);
```

this is my code.
**EDIT**

ahm i also Forgot when trailing zeros"00000001" it returns "1".

Comment: I'd prefer a random GUID http://www.guidgenerator.com/ or UUID: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

Comment: it is save to a db and it is my project that i get from my Professor. Thankyou Btw.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to read that wall of code.  Step into it in a debugger and see where the behavior fails to match your assumptions.  Learning to program means learning how to debug.